# Problems using branching in Arm Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

So my code just displays both outputs like it is not branching to the `then` statement. I just started learning arm and I cant figure out what is going on and why it won't branch. Any help would be great as I have been looking at this for a total of about 5 hours with no progress.

The program is supposed to take a number as input and display if it is larger or less than 100

```
ldr r3, =intInput
ldr r3, [r3]
cmp r3, #100
bhs then

then:   
ldr r0, =strOutputNumLarger
bl printf

else:
ldr r0, =strOutputNumSmaller
bl printf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional branch `bhs then` goes to `then:` if the branch is taken, and also if it is not taken. 
There is no apparent branch to `else:`. Surely the first branch should be `bhs else:` and the messages swapped.

After the first branch and link there is another pair of similar instructions, at `else:`. So there should be an unconditional branch to prevent the `then:` code block falling through to the `else:` code block, by skipping over it.

So the code should be

```
ldr r3, =intInput
ldr r3, [r3]
cmp r3, #100
bhs else                       ; changed destination

then:
ldr r0, =strOutputNumSmaller   ; swapped messages
bl printf
b cont                         ; skip next code block

else:
ldr r0, =strOutputNumLarger
bl printf

cont:
```

Comment: You sir are may savior, I have been messing with this simple program for hours. On another note do you know why i am getting "bash: echo44: command not found" after the outputs?

Comment: Only a vague guess: it might have something to do with the way you are terminating the messages.